# File handle failed to read second time

Tags: regex, perl

How can I read from a file handle for the second time inside `foreach` loop in Perl?

```
foreach $a (@b){
    while(my $line = <IN>){
        if($line = /$a/){
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is not processing the second element from the list `@b`. How to make it possible?

Comment: @zdim Do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: Explain what do you want to do. What is @b ? Where is your file handler ?

Comment: Assume <IN> is a file handler

Comment: @Phx Dev  @b is array which has many values.<IN> is a file handler reading information from some other file.If the reading line matches with any elements from the array,it has to display that line from the file.

Comment: `< >` is a readline operation. `IN` is a file *handle*, not a handler. (Also, don't use bareword filehandles.)

Comment: Why don't you simply swap the two loops? Do `while (<IN>)` on the outside, then you don't have to worry about reading files again.

Comment: @cherry (Didn't see this until now -- and you've got a really nice answer :)

Comment: @zdim Yes,I got a good answers from these contributors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inner loop, `while(my $line = <IN>)`, extracts lines from the `IN` handle until it reaches the end of the file.

When your outer loop, `foreach $a (@b)`, tries to read from `IN` again, it's still at end-of-file. The first iteration of the `foreach` loop consumes all lines from the file, leaving nothing for the other iterations.

There are several possible ways to fix this:

- [Seek](https://perldoc.pl/functions/seek) back to the beginning of `IN` before you attempt to read from it again:

  ```
  foreach $a (@b){
      seek IN, 0, 0
          or die "Cannot seek(): $!";
      while (my $line = <IN>) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  However, this only works for real files, not pipes or sockets or terminals.
- Read the whole file into memory up front, then iterate over a normal array:

  ```
  my @lines = <IN>;
  foreach $a (@b){
      foreach my $line (@lines) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  However, if the file is big, this will use a lot of memory.
- Switch the order of the two loops:

  ```
  while (my $line = <IN>) {
      foreach $a (@b) {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  This is my favorite. Now you only need to read from the file once. `@b` is already in memory, so you can iterate over it as many times as you want.

---

Side notes:

- Don't use bareword filehandles like `IN`. Normal variables (such as `$IN`) are pretty much superior in every way.
- Don't use variables called `$a` or `$b`. They're a bit special because Perl uses them in [`sort`](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#sort-SUBNAME-LIST).
- My personal preference is to never use `< >`. It's weirdly overloaded (it can mean either [`readline`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/readline) or [`glob`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/glob), depending on the exact syntax you use) and it isn't terribly intuitive. Using `readline` means there's never any syntactic ambiguity and even programmers with no Perl experience can figure out what it does.

With those changes:

```
while (my $line = readline $IN) {
    foreach my $re (@regexes) {
        if ($line =~ /$re/) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @melponmene Thanks for your detailed explanation.I understand about this concept well.

Answer (score 2):

You read within a `while` loop until the filehandle is exhausted (reached `EOF` end of file).
If you don't close and reopen your filehandle you won't read anymore from it in the second iteration of the outer loop.

If the amount of data you read from the filehandle is no so large you could read the file into an array variable and iterate over the content of the array variable.

For example:

```
my @filecontent = <IN>;
foreach $item_of_b (@b){
    foreach my $line_of_file (@filecontent){
        if($line_of_file =~ /$item_of_b/){
            print $line_of_file;
        }
    }
}
```

And `$a` and `$b` should not be used as variable names, they are special due to sorting.