# Nested For loop Iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python and trying to open a file and print a line that is matching two values (one value from a list and second value being a static value). I get the expected output for first iteration but it looks like the for loop is not running any other iterations.

Below is the code:

```py
text_file = open(Path, 'r')
list_1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
static_value = 'Test'

for term in list_1:
    for line in text_file:
        if term in line and static_value in line:
            print(line)
```

Example contents of file:

One

One Test

Two

Two Test

Three

Three Test

Comment: pls show us the contents of your text file. thanks.

Comment: you can only iterate on an opened file once. You have to re-open it for each loop

Comment: Once you've got to the end of the file, there are no more lines in the file to loop over. Either `seek()` back to the beginning of the file, or swap the loops: `for line in text_file: for term in list_1:`
:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54862214/1848654 (the only wrinkle being that it's in a completely different programming language).

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response.
Swapping the for loops did it. 
Will also look in seek()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you swap your `for` loops. A more elegant way is to use `any()` to check for the match like so:

```
for line in text_file:
    if any(term in line for term in list_1) and static_value in line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Swapping the for loops did it. I did not use any() function so far, I will research on any() function.